# Unexpected scrolling down after pressing keydown on Bootsrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My webpage seems normal using *Bootstrap*, but whenever I press keydown (down key), the screen scrolled down and **show unexpected white space**, because it has reached at the end of `background-image` that have size of **1798px * 1080px**.

Please see in picture:
[image]

Here's my **code** below:

**HTML**:

```
 <body style="background:url(assets/img/back-body-base.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">              
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-lg-1" style="background-color:#2C2B2B;padding-bottom: 100%;margin-bottom: -100%;"></nav>
        <div class="col-lg-11" style="overflow: hidden">
            <div class="row">
                <header>
                    <div align="center" class="position-header">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <div>
                                <img src="assets/img/logo.png" height="25%" width="25%"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-top-10">
                                <img src="assets/img/sublogo.png" width="25%" height="25%"/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-11">
                    <div class="p-top-50"></div>
             <div class="row">                                          

                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="monday"  class="dayfloat daybutton-first w-200 dayList"    data-type="day"  data-daycount = "1"   tabindex="1">Mondat</div>
                                <div id="tuesday"  class="dayfloat daybutton-center w-200 dayList"    data-type="day" data-daycount = "2"    tabindex="2">Tuesday</div>
                                <div id="wednesday"  class="dayfloat daybutton-center w-200 dayList"    data-type="day" data-daycount = "3"    tabindex="3">Wednesday</div>
                                <div id="thursday"  class="dayfloat daybutton-center w-200 dayList"    data-type="day" data-daycount = "4"    tabindex="4">Thrusday</div>
                                <div id="friday"  class="dayfloat daybutton-center w-200 dayList"    data-type="day" data-daycount = "5"    tabindex="5">Friday</div>
                                <div id="saturday"  class="dayfloat daybutton-center w-200 dayList"    data-type="day" data-daycount = "6"    tabindex="6">Saturday</div>
                                <div id="sunday"   class="dayfloat daybutton-end w-200 dayList"   data-type="day"   data-daycount = "7"    tabindex="7">Sunday</div>        
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="p-top-50"></div>
                                <div id="hour2" class="hour-to-hour-line"></div>                                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="p-top-100"></div>
                                <div id="thumbnail" class="thumbs"></div>                                           
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                </div>                      
            </div>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
.p-top-10 {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.p-top-30 {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.p-top-50 {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Additional Info :

> 1. I've implement keydown event using `jQuery`, so I can move to another
>      `<div>`
> 2. The resolution of back-bode-base.jpg' is **1798px*1080px**

Please help me into this.

Comment: could you add the jquery and bootstrap `<link>` tags? cause as i tested the html i dont seem to see any problems.

Comment: have u tried style="background: #000 url(assets/img/back-body-base.jpg) no-repeat;"

Comment: Hi @FarazShuja, thanks it works...however, do you know how to disable scroll when pressing keydown ?

Comment: this is a default browser event, on click of keydown it will scroll the page. I can help better if you can create some jsfiddle of ur problem

Comment: btw u can upvote the comment if you like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use below css, this will make your background fixed to 100%

```
body { 
   background: url(./images/back-body-base.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```